# КатАрсис или кАтарсис?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Какова лингвистическая норма в русском языке относительно ударения в слове **катарсис**?
Существует ли строгое правило на этот счёт?

Answer (score 2):

> Какова лингвистическая норма в русском языке относительно ударения в
>   слове «катарсис»?

Когда-то единственно правильным считалось ударение в этом слове на первом слоге: ***кАтарсис.***

Когда-то... Но не сейчас. В *Большом орфоэпическом словаре* (***Каленчук М. Л., Касаткин Л. Л., Касаткина Р. Ф. "Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: норма и её варианты" , М.: АСТ-ПРЕСС КНИГА, 2012***), созданном в *Институте русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова Российской академии наук* под руководством *Л. Л. Касаткина,* никакого предпочтения варианту произношения слова ***катарсис***  с ударением на первом слоге ***(кАтарсис)*** по сравнению с вариантом произношения с ударением на втором слоге ***(катАрсис)*** не отдаётся. Варианты эти считаются в *Большом орфоэпическом словаре* равноправными.

См.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

.

Интересно то, что *Зарва  Майя Владимировна*  из этих двух  вариантов **более предпочтительным** в наши дни считает вариант с ударением на втором слоге (***Зарва М. В. "Русское словесное ударение", М., 2001***):

> ***катАрсис***

Такого же мнения придерживается и автор ***Словаря правильной русской речи*** (2008), выпущенного *Институтом лингвистических исследований Российской академии наук*, *Соловьев Николай Васильевич:*

> ***катАрсис*** и *уход. **кАтарсис***

Answer (score 1):

До строгого правила ещё далеко.

Народ читающий ставит ударение, как удобнее, а удобнее на второй слог. Народ, слышавший произношение педагогов старшего поколения, произносит, как они, то есть на первый.

И так было много-много лет подряд...

> [Ударение падает только первый слог](http://gruzdoff.ru/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81) - кАтарсис. Это императивная норма.
>   Так говорят авторитетные орфоэпические словари Аванесова и Резниченко.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Приведу скриншоты из других современных словарей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот на Словарь ударений и можно было бы ориентироваться, если бы с ним не спорил другой словарь - Русское словесное ударение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это значит, что при любом раскладе Вас никто не упрекнёт в неверном ударении, но старшее поколение остаётся при своём: ударение на первый слог.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте цитаты в виде текста (при необходимости воспользуйтесь выделением «цитата»), а не изображения.